# import contacts from gmail/hotmail/yahoo to php

Tags: php, yahoo, hotmail, google-contacts-api

i would like to import contacts from gmail/hotmail/yahoo to my php applications just like those found in social network.

i've read how gmail does it but im still not very clear about it. it says i would need to do a http request like this `https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@self`

but how should i send this info?? i tried running this on the browser and it returns "Cannot make anonymous request without explicit user ID in the URL" so how can i pass the correct user ID then??

for yahoo, the Yahoo! Address Book API is deprecated and now we should use Contacts API. have anyone use this b4??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that URL corresponds to [`osapi.people`](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Osapi.people_%28v0.9%29), which suggests that you can replace the token `@me` with a profile name.

I verified this by visiting that URL and replacing the `@me` with my own Google login.

[The JSON-RPC documentation](http://www.opensocial.org/Technical-Resources/opensocial-spec-v081/rpc-protocol.html) suggests that you can replace the `@self` token with `@friends` to get a friend list, assuming the application making the request is authorized to pull down this data.

Unfortunately this is all I know, discovered through a few minutes in Google finding the docs.