# I need import yahoo contact through api

Tags: php, yahoo

I need import yahoo contacts through api in to my application . any one have idea or any example please ?

Comment: What did you try ? Do you have some specific problem with your code ? *(People on SO are generally OK to help ; but don't really like "give me the code" questions)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [import contacts from gmail/hotmail/yahoo to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211868/import-contacts-from-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-to-php)

Comment: Many more here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+import+yahoo+contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the CloudSponge [contact importer API](http://www.cloudsponge.com).  If you use our [open source PHP wrapper](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/php/) you'll get up and running really quickly and you'll get all the major address books (not just Yahoo).

I work for CloudSponge, drop me a line at support@cloudsponge.com if you have any questions.

Comment: So no need to pay the membership from cloudsponge? this code is open source?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Yahoo! Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/) (documentation and examples):

> Contacts are relationships that exist in your Yahoo! address book, such as those entered from across the Yahoo! Network like Yahoo! Mail and Yahoo! Messenger. *The API enables your application to leverage those relationships by reading a user's Contacts information* safely and securely, respecting that user's privacy and permission settings.